# Show the first row of the table in alert message using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to show the first row of the table in alert message at a time

```
function GetCellValues() {
    var rows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
    for (var c = 0; c < rows.length; c++) {
        var row = rows[c];
        var inputs = row.getElementsByTagName('input');
        for (var k = 0; k < inputs.length; k++) {
            alert(inputs[k].value);

            //here I want some code to show the first table row at a time.        
        }
    }
}

window.onload = function () {
    makeTable();
};
```

Comment: what is happening here? are you getting multiple alert for a row?

Comment: here  I am getting a single single alert for each <td>. But I want a single row in one alert box at a time...

Comment: I guess,  each <td> has single input element

Comment: yes each <td> has single input textbox

Comment: have you tried the soln what I have given?

Comment: I want to concatenate the one row... but not able to do this.... please help me.

Comment: aren't you getting all input value of each <tr> at a time in an alert?

Comment: plaese explain your requirement or setup a jsFiddle so that we can help you out.

Comment: No I am not getting all input value of each <tr> at a time in an alert...

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
function GetCellValues() {
    var rows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
    for (var c = 0; c < rows.length; c++) {
        var row = rows[c];
        var inputs = row.getElementsByTagName('input');
        var inputValList=[];
        for (var k = 0; k < inputs.length; k++) {
           // alert(inputs[k].value);
             inputValList.push(inputs[k].value);

        }
        if(inputValList.length>0){
           alert(inputValList);
        }
    }
}
```

I just hope...this will solve your problem.